# Postfix rejecting to address

Tags: email, postfix, configuration

I'm trying to setup postfix on ubuntu. I only want to allow sending of email from local connections with no authentication. When I try to send emails I'm getting the following errors:

```
550 5.1.1 <my_address@gmail.com>: Recipient address rejected: gmail.com
554 5.5.1 Error: no valid recipients
```

This error occurs no matter what the to address is set to. I've been testing with the following:

```
# telnet localhost 25

Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 server.domain.com ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)

ehlo localhost
mail from: root@localhost
rcpt to: my_address@gmail.com
data
Subject: My first mail on Postfix

Hi,
Are you there?
regards,
Admin
.
quit250-server.domain.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
250 2.1.0 Ok
550 5.1.1 <my_address@gmail.comt>: Recipient address rejected: gmail.com
554 5.5.1 Error: no valid recipients
221 2.7.0 Error: I can break rules, too. Goodbye.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

My main.cf file look like this:

```
# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = server.domain.comt
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = server.domain.com, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
default_transport = error
relay_transport = error
inet_protocols = ipv4
```

Not sure how to proceed as google has not turned up anything related to my issue.

Answer (score 3):

Normally this is a hostname/DNS issue. I'm assuming server.domain.com is not the actual hostname of the server, but make sure it is a proper FQDN. If it is not an internet facing server with a real external hostname, use a .local domain (I sometimes use .internal at home to avoid conflicting with zeroconf). Check your hosts file, /etc/hostname, /etc/mailname, and the values of myhostname, mydestination, myorigin.

Also in the config above there is a typo in myhostname.

Comment: Yes, server.domain.com is not the actual hostname :) There was a problem with the hostname, I've updated the the sever with the correct settings but it's still giving the same error as before